# Passing JFrame as a paramater

Tags: java, swing, pass-by-reference

Trying to pass my `JFrame` through an `actioncall` to add more components to the JFrame later, depending on the action call.

This has to be possible, but maybe I am taking the wrong approach?

```
private static void base() {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    ... (components added, etc.)
    pay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
            buildGUI("Pay", jf);
        }
    });
    ...(pack and setVisible)
}

private static void buildGUI(String type, JFrame jf){
    ...do stuff here (add more components)...    
}
```

I've tried to add components to the `JFrame` through `buildGUI` and it doesn't reflect any changes.

I've read somewhere that doing it this way is only reference-of-type, and it duplicates the original value not actually changing the original JFrame.

Any suggestions thanks.

Comment: You could create a custom class which implements `ActionListener`, which takes `JFrame` as a parameter to the constructor, equally, you could use the `Action` API and do a simular thing

Comment: Have you tried declaring JFrame as a class(global) variable?